# meet -Inf or NaN as the result for genetic algorithm using matlab

Tags: matlab, nan, genetic-algorithm

I sometimes get -Inf or NaN as the final value of my target function when I am using matlab ga toolbox doing the minimization. But if I do the optimization again with exactly the same option set up, I get a finite answer... Could anyone tell me why this is the case? and how could I solve the problem? Thanks very much!

Comment: We're not going to be able to help with the `NaN`/`Inf` issue really without seeing code. Debugging is a good bet. Start printing out each line and see which one firs goes bad and then backtrack.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation and examples for [`ga`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/ga.html) are bad about this and barely mention the stochastic nature of this method (though if you're using it maybe you would be aware). If you wish to have repeatable results, you should always specify a seed value when perform stochastic simulations. This can be done in at least two ways. You can use the [`rng`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) function:

```
rng(0);
```

where `0` is the seed value. Or you can possibly use the `'rngstate'` field if you specify the optimization as a [problem structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/ga.html#inputarg_problem). See more here on [reproducing results](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/reproducing-your-results-1.html).

If you're doing any sort of experiments you should be specifying a seed. That way you can repeat a run if necessary to check why something may have happened or to obtain more finely-grained data. Just change the seed value to another positive integer if you want to run again.

Answer (score 1):

The Genetic Algorithm is a stochastic algorithm, which means it does not explore the same problem space every time you run it. On each run it will be trying different solutions, and occasionally it is running into a solution on which your target function is ill-behaved.

Without knowing more about your specific problem, all I can really suggest is that you take a closer look at your target function and see if you can restrict it so that it does not explode to negative infinity. Look at the solution returned by the GA when you get these crazy target values, and see if you can adjust your target function so that it does not return infinite values for such solutions.